# Webhooks for Facebook Messenger: Not sending message during cURL POST

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

My webhook GET method from facebook during set up is working. I am already able to get the message data:

```
{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"xxxxxxxxx","time":1632712256226,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"xxxxxxxxxx"},"recipient":{"id":"xxxxxxxxx"},"timestamp":1632712256025,"message":{"mid":"m_V-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","text":"new"}}]}]}
```

But whenever I cURL post to facebook messenger, it does not send the message.

```
$reply_message = '
    {
        "messaging_type": "RESPONSE",
        "recipient": {
            "id":"<ID in sender ID given by json above>"
        },
        "message": {
            "text": "hello, world!"
        }
    }
    ';

send_reply($access_token, $reply_message);

function send_reply($access_token, $reply_message){
        $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/me/messages?access_token=". $access_token;
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_string);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

        $data = curl_exec($curl);
        $result = json_decode($data, TRUE);
        curl_close($curl);

        return $result;
    }
```

Server response:

```
POST /facebook_messenger/fb_webhook.php 200 OK
```

Comment: What does Facebook return when you do that curl request?

Comment: on my server's console I get this message from facebook every time a message is sent

"POST /facebook_messenger/fb_webhook.php 200 OK "

This is using ngrok

Comment: Sounds like the POST request reached your webhook okay, and your system responded with 200 OK. Why you are not getting any data (or _think_ you didn't), we can't tell, because you have not shown any code of the webhook script yet.

Answer (score 0):

Added `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` to curl

Complete code:

```
$access_token="xxxxxxx";
$my_verify_token=""yyyyyyy;

$challenge=$_GET['hub_challenge'];
    $verify_token=$_GET['hub_verify_token'];

    if($my_verify_token === $verify_token){
        echo $challenge;
        exit;
    }

$response = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $response = json_decode($response, true);

    $message = $response['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];

    $reply_message = '
    {
        "messaging_type": "RESPONSE",
        "recipient": {
            "id": '. $response['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'] .'
        },
        "message": {
            "text": "hello, world!"
        }
    }
    ';

    send_reply($access_token, $reply_message);

    function send_reply($access_token='', $reply=''){
        $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/me/messages?access_token=$access_token";
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $reply);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $data = curl_exec($curl);
        $result = json_decode($data, TRUE);
        // curl_close($curl);

        return $result;
    }
```